# How to insert data in table only if data exists in another PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to know how I can insert a row into a table only if one of the parameters also exist in another table.

I have two tables, `Goals [goal_id, username...] Activities[username, goal_id, activity_id..]`.

With a 1-many carnality, so a new activity must have the goal id. I have set up a REST service, the problem is currently the user could insert a activity connected to a goal that doesn't belong to them, so I am looking for a way to `INSERT` only if the *goal_id* supplied belongs to them in the `user_goal` table.

```
if (isset($_POST['activity'])) {
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $connected_goal = $_POST['connected_goal'];
    if (!isset($_POST['title']) || !isset($_POST['description']) || !isset($_POST['connected_goal'])) {
        echo "Missing fields in the request! New activities MUST contain; title, description AND connected_goal";
    }
    else {
        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("insert into user_activity(username,title,description,goal_id) values(?,?,?,?)")) {
            $stmt->bind_param("sssi", $apiusername, $title, $description, $connected_goal);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
            echo "ACTIVITY ACCEPTED";
        }
        else {
            echo "POST Request failed, please check all parameters against documentation.";
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It doesn't anwser the issue but, the `$title = $POST['title']` and the 2 others should be placed AFTER the `if(!isset($POST[title]) ...` is checked, because if they are not set, you do 3 line for nothing. Just sayin....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a simple join statement to find whether a records exist in another table for that username. Try below query

```
SELECT table1.username, table1.goal_id, COUNT(table2.username) as total FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.username=table1.username
GROUP BY table1.username
HAVING total >=1
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case you should add a foreign key constraint in your user_activity table. Something like the following query will add the constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE user_activity ADD CONSTRAINT fk_goal_id FOREIGN KEY (goal_id) references user_goals(goal_id);
```